# Software copyrights - can i use screen name instead of real name?

Tags: copyright, software, india

I'm trying to use my screen name (say "Cyfrost") instead of my real name (say "Billy Raymond") for a copyright notice inside my software, by doing so, I'm hoping to achieve credit to my work.

Here's a better illustration of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

and not this: (assuming my real name is Billy Raymond)

[image]

**Can i use my screen name in the Copyright notice label instead of my real name?**

I'm relatively new here, so please suggest any corrections.

1. My software will be closed source, but always freely available on the internet.
2. For legal jurisdiction, I live in India and I do not plan on Registering copyrights for these software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a pen name in a copyright notice.

Comment: are there any caveats to doing that? I'm interested in knowing more.

Comment: Ask [George Eliot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Eliot) aka Mary Anne Evans